# Is there way to get User Role and group from Ad/Ldap without specifying user passwoard?

Tags: c#, vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I need to get the network domain name associated with the current user without entering user password or credential.

I have tried to get User group and getting error "a local error has occurred".

Below code I have used.

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName))
{
    try
    {
        // add the users groups to the result
        var groupList =
            UserPrincipal
                .FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Environment.UserName )
                .GetGroups()
                .Select(group => group.Name)
                .ToList();
        groupList.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: LogError( "Unable to query Active Directory.", ex );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory doesn't allow anonymous access per default.  So yes, you'll have to bind first using whichever method suits you, if you want to retrieve anything else but the RootDSE entry.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this as i have dig in to RootDSE?  When I  find any of the property value than it will thronging  exception "A local error has occurred.".

Comment: Your first question was about the domain of the current user.  That's not typically an information you retrieve via LDAP, but if you are interested in domain related attributes of the rootDSE, you can get that via LDAP with an anonymous session - use an empty baseDn and searchScope "base".  User information, though, is not accessible without a successful bind operation. I don't know about your error message, looks like you can connect, so your bind could be the culprit.